# All exceptions are objects in c++?

Tags: c++, object, exception

In some literature, like http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Exception_Handling , they treat all exceptions as objects, even if they are throwing a fundamental type or a pointer.

I want to ask why we call them objects, if sometimes they are not objects.
If i don't understand correctly, please correct me.

Comment: Anything that occupies memory is an *object*. The point of *object orientation* is to shift the focus on to the data by binding the operations the data accepts with the data itself. Obviously only user defined types allow you to do this *programatically* but that doesn't stop fundamental types from being objects.

Comment: I think best thing to say is that "all exceptions are lvalues".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Q:** "I want to ask why we call them objects, if sometimes they are not
>   objects"

Anything that occupies memory is an object. The point of *object orientation* is to shift the focus on to the *data* (object) by binding the operations the data accepts with the data itself.

Obviously only *user defined types* allow you to do this programatically but that doesn't stop *fundamental types* from being objects.

According to the `C++11` standard:

**1.8** The C++ object model [**intro.object**]

> 1 The constructs in a C ++ program create, destroy, refer to, access,
>   and manipulate objects. An object is a region of storage.

Here is what Wikipedia says:

[Object (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29)

> In computer science, an object is a location in memory having a value
>   and possibly referenced by an identifier. An object can be a variable,
>   a data structure, or a function. In the class-based object-oriented
>   programming paradigm, "object" refers to a particular instance of a
>   class where the object can be a combination of variables, functions,
>   and data structures.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can use a *primitive* like `const char*` or `int` to throw and catch an exception properly

```
 try {
     if(bad_condition_one) {
         throw "Bad condition 1 was hit.";
     }
     else if(bad_condition_two) {
         throw 42;
     }
 }
 catch(const char* msg) {
     std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
 }
 catch(int code) {
     std::cerr << code << std::endl;
 }
```

But it's certainly not a good idea to do so. You should use exception values derived from `std::exception` in first place. And catch them as `const` references like:

```
 try {
     if(bad_condition_one) {
         throw std::runtime_error("Bad condition 1 was hit.");
     }
 }
 catch(const std::exception& ex) {
     std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
 }
```

Define your conception of ***object*** more properly in your question please (did you mean `class`, `struct` or `union` type actually?).

Comment: Side Note: Although legal, programmers will hate anybody doing that.

Comment: @DieterLücking Certainly agreed, but that wasn't in question primarily as the OP stands.

Comment: So there can be a other than standard definition of an object?
I mean the one: Object is an instance of class.

Comment: @Arlic _"So there can be a other than standard definition of an object?"_ Not that I'm aware of any _standard definitions_ for ***object*** in context of the current c++ standards?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ
In context of c++ standards.

Comment: @Arlic Are you sure, you're not asking about a XY-problem? Exceptions are allowed to be of any type. They can even be caught with `catch(...)`, for unknown ones.