# Does object-oriented programming imply exclusively using objects?

Tags: c++, function, oop

After reading through a C++ tutorial, I am left wondering: in actual object oriented programming, do we try to use objects whenever possible?

For example, if I have a class Cents, which holds an amount of cents, and I want to add functionality to add two Cents objects, would I write a member function, or a non-member function? I.e.:

```
Cents c1;
Cents c2;

Cents c3 = addCents(c1,c2);
```

or

```
Cents c3 = c1.add(c2);
```

Comment: Your example doesn't match your question... in both cases objects are used.

Comment: @awesomeyi I think the OP means, one uses a member function, one does not ....?

Comment: I guess the question is free functions operating on an object versus member functions.

Comment: I would overload the `+` operator myself with a global friend function.

Comment: @NathanOliver I've noticed a lot of operator overloading in OO code out there

Comment: Use objects when and where they make sense. If they don't, smurf them. Just get the job done the cleanest, simplest way possible. There is no point to being a OO fundamentalist.

Comment: @Funkyguy If the language allows it and it is natural to do so then why not.  I hate having to write `object1.add(object2)` when I can just do `object 1 + object2`

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree with you, thats why you overload the operator.  I was just agreeing with you

Comment: I think you may be confused in your terminology. This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30649112/3807729

Comment: Actually there is no 'object oriented programming' - It is nothing more than a vague idea.

Comment: See [Scott Meyer's Effective C++](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-Specific-Programs-Professional-Computing/dp/0321334876) items 23: "Prefer non-member non-friend functions to member functions" and 24: "Declare non-member functions when type conversions should apply to all parameters"

Answer (score 1):

> Does object-oriented programming imply exclusively using objects?

Yes

> Is C++ a object-oriented programming language

**NO**

C++ is a multi-paradiagm language that also happens to support OO. Thus allowing you to use the proper technique to solve the problem (not all problems are best solved using OO).

> if I have a class Cents, which holds an amount of cents, and I want to add functionality to add two Cents objects, would I write a member function, or a non-member function? I.e.:

If you are writing the function `add()` rather than `operator+()`, then I personally I would make it a member function. This is because I keep all the functionality that can happen on Cents centralized in one place (I know that the only thing that can manipulate the objects are its members).

On the other hand if I was writing `operato+()` then I would use a non member function. Not because it is not OO. But because of the extra functionality that it can provide (I would just make it a friend to document its tight coupling to the the class).

```
Cents  x;
Cents  y;

y = x + 5;  // Will activate member function (if provided).
y = 5 + x;  // Will NOT activate member function 
            //          but potentially can activate a non member function.
```

In reality it depends what you want. Normally compiler generated conversions is a bad (or smelly) thing. But in this one use case it could be argued that it provides useful intuitive functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we try to use objects as much as possible.

Even more so, objects that have private data set at construction, for instance:

```
class Cents{
    public:
        Cents(int amount); //constructor
    private:
        int xAmount;
}

Cents c1 = Cents(int amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either way is fine. C++ doesn't require to use member functions (some other languages might) so using member functions or not is a matter of choice.

You could also overload operator by defining following function in Cents class declaration:

```
    Cents operator+(const Cents&);
```

And then write:

```
    Cents c3 = c1 + c2;
```

Nice and simple. When and if to use stand alone function, member function or operator overloading has no simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

To explain about Object Oriented Programming, in this we treat all the "Real time entities " as Objects and hence class is the Type of the Object.
The whole concept of oops is to mainly make things easier be it developing or maintaining the code.
Before coming to your example, oops is constructed in some primary pillars like

- Abstraction : Creating a class with properties thise belongs to the class and with only those behaviours (methods) it can do
- Encapsulation : binding variables and methods in a class by use of access specifiers.
- Polymorphism : This is the concept on which most of the design patterns are built on. Gives the ability for dynamic binding. As you may know the definition, same method doing different functions when called with different parametets or different objects.
- Inheritance : mostly misunderstood to be makimg easy to be able to reuse the code, But actually should be used where ever "Generalization" can be applied . In other words, should be used wherever IS-A relationship exists.

  Hence in your example, a `Cent` class cant have an `add()` method because a `Cent` can't add. But `CurrencyCalculator` class can add hence can have the `add()` mathod.